# Firebase Auth: Secure Check, if User is logged in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am authorizing a user on every AJX-Request he sends. Herefore I call a function at the beginning of my AJX-Function. This gives me a callback with the userID and the ID Token:

```
userID = currentUser.uid;
currentUser.getIdToken().then(function(data) {
   token = data;
   __callback( userID, token);
});
```

Then I call the request and pass over the ID and token.
On the server side, I check the token, to which userID it belongs to.
Are these two IDs equal, the user is logged in.

But what, if the user knows the userID and the token, he can modify the two vars and send them via the AJX-Call. Then the user is immediately logged in.

Is that the best way to verify the user server-sided? Or how should this be done?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the concern is here.  A user can technically always know their UID and ID token by invoking auth APIs after they've been authenticated.  The ID token is their own secret, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if the user knows the userID and the token, he can modify the two vars and send them via the AJX-Call.

That is actually not possible. To create an ID token, you need to sign it with your project's private key. Since that is never sent over the wire, hackers can't do the same.

Unless of course they know the user's credentials, in which case they can use the Firebase Authentication API to sign in/create such a token. There's not a lot you can do against that.

Comment: yes, they won't get the private key. But I thought, if another user gets (however he does) the uid and the token of the admin, he could pass this two things with the AJX-Call and get alle information the admin could get. This "hacker" would not be logged in with firebase at this moment, but he would get the server-information, wouldn't he?